# Subplot from function in a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I am trying to generate a subplot with heat maps which I obtained with seaborn. When I try to create the subplots, I get a figure with three empty boxes and then the heat maps. I haven't been able to figure out how to assing the maps to the boxes. Here is my code:

```
def plot_cf_mat(matrix, save, figure_name):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.heatmap(matrix/np.sum(matrix), annot=True, fmt = '.2%', cmap=sns.light_palette((.376, .051, .224)))
    #ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix\n\n');
    ax.set_xlabel('\nPredicted Values')
    ax.set_ylabel('Actual Values ');

    ## Ticket labels - List must be in alphabetical order
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['False','True'])
    ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['False','True'])
    
    if save:
        plt.savefig("".join(["cf_mat_", figure_name, ".jpg"]), bbox_inches='tight')

    return ax

#Plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
i = 0
for row in axes:
    fun.plot_cf_mat(matrix = cf_mat_x_clssifr[i][-1], save = False, figure_name = None)
    i+=1
plt.show()
```

Here is what I get
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the created axes to your function or to `sns.heatmap`. Pass the row to your function (notice the `ax=row` part):

```
#Plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
i = 0
for row in axes:
    fun.plot_cf_mat(matrix = cf_mat_x_clssifr[i][-1], save = False, figure_name = None, ax=row)
    i+=1
plt.show()
```

And now plot your heatmap on that ax object (notice the `ax` argument in the function and passing the object to `sns.heatmap`):

```
def plot_cf_mat(matrix, save, figure_name, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    # fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.heatmap(matrix/np.sum(matrix), annot=True, fmt = '.2%', cmap=sns.light_palette((.376, .051, .224)), ax=ax)
```